# Identical math appears differently if defined in a \newcommand

Tags: math-mode, macros, fontsize

My short example `.tex` line is:

```
$\myCommand$ or $\boldsymbol{d}_{x}^{\textrm{word1},\textrm{word2}}$
```

Where I have defined:

```
\newcommand{\myCommand}{
    \boldsymbol{d}_{x}^{\textrm{word1},\textrm{word2}} %identical to second version
}
```

Yet the result has very noticeably different sizes for the superscripts:

[image: result_is_different]

Any idea what is going on? I would like to construct some utility functions for lots of math and this seems to be stopping me.

EDIT:

Here is a full working minimal example as suggested by Sigur, which includes the suspected issue package:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\newcommand{\myCommand}{\boldsymbol{d}_{x}^{\textrm{word1},\textrm{word2}}}

\begin{document}
$\myCommand$ or $\boldsymbol{d}_{x}^{\textrm{word1},\textrm{word2}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce your output with my minimal working code. So, some extra part of your code is responsible for it.

Comment: Try with this: `\documentclass{report}\usepackage{amsmath}\newcommand{\myCommand}{\boldsymbol{d}_{x}^{\textrm{word1},\textrm{word2}}}\begin{document}$\myCommand$ or $\boldsymbol{d}_{x}^{\textrm{word1},\textrm{word2}}$\end{document}`

Comment: It was extremely helpful to know it was something to do with my setup. I see that your example indeed does not reproduce my problem. Adding my template to the minimal example also does not introduce the problem, but adding all of my packages does!

Comment: It turns out that `\usepackage{breqn}` causes the issue. I can't even remember why I added that in the first place - I guess this is a good example of package hygiene. Thanks very much for the help, my apologies, I had thought it was a maybe wider issue.

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be caused by `breqn`. Your picture suggests that `\textrm` is not scaled properly as the texts are of normal size. This is a classical problem and can be resolved by loading `amsmath`.

Comment: Hi Ruixi, I've added a full example rather than a snippet. I'm interested if you experience the same issue with both `amsmath` and `breqn` (I do, with both)

Comment: Thank you for providing a complete example. I have come up with an alternative solution if you want to keep `breqn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve automatic equation line breaking, `breqn` has to make drastic changes. These changes include, unfortunately, the primitive `\mathchoice` (in the supplementary package `mathstyle`). This change breaks `amstext`’s `\text`, which uses `\mathchoice`.

We have two more options here (in addition to removing `breqn`).

### Option 1

Use `\mathrm` instead of `\textrm`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\newcommand{\myCommand}{\boldsymbol{d}_{x}^{\mathrm{word1},\mathrm{word2}}}

\begin{document}
$\myCommand$ or $\boldsymbol{d}_{x}^{\mathrm{word1},\mathrm{word2}}$
\end{document}
```

### Option 2

Not recommended. Restore the original meaning of `\mathchoice` locally.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myCommand}{%
  \begingroup
    \let\mathchoice\@@mathchoice
    \boldsymbol{d}_{x}^{\textrm{word1},\textrm{word2}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\myCommand$ or $\boldsymbol{d}_{x}^{\textrm{word1},\textrm{word2}}$
\end{document}
```

Both methods produce the following output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

As I don't want to leave this question hanging for others: this issue was caused by the inclusion of:

```
\usepackage{breqn}
```

in the preamble. Simply including the package above with no other options, and the superscript texts will be incorrect in macros but not in normal mathmode, which is a strange incompatibility. Removing the above package solves my problem.